# Does Windows 8 require any sort of Virus protection?

Tags: windows-8, anti-virus

I have read about how Windows 8 is better and has better built in security... So the question is, do I really need third party Virus protection, or is the built in security good enough?

Comment: When is a virus scanner *good enough*? When it uses few system resources? When it has all management function to deploy and monitor it in a managed corporation? Etc etc... No clear answer for 'good enough'.

Comment: I guess by "good enough" I really mean the best available, but I guess that is kind of subjective... So the real question is, Do I need third party virus protection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built in antivirus from the MS which is called Windows Defender but it has all the features of the MS Essential antivirus (except the right click scan option) which we have used on old Windows version.

[image]

Just update it regular and you will be safe.  You can turn on its `Real time protection` option which will keep safe you from the malware and viruses.

[image]

If you want to add it in the right click menu to scan the drives and folder which you want immediate instead using the custom search's lengthy process you can see my this [post](https://superuser.com/a/494065/86550).

Comment: Update it regular is a bit misleading. Windows Defenders updates itself automatically of course

Comment: You need to update it regularly in the case Windows update is turned off or auto update of Windows defender is turned off...

Answer (score 2):

The built in one, Windows Defender is really good, as long as you update it regularly, you do not need any third party tools.

See this report by AV Comparatives.

> http://www.av-comparatives.org/images/docs/avc_per_201210_en.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your usage. For the average consumer, I would say Windows Defender is enough. But, if you are a power user, you know like install lots of softwares, browse a lot of websites etc, I would suggest to invest in a full fledged security suite. I personally use Kaspersky Internet Security 2013.

Also the link given by [HackToHell](https://superuser.com/users/71027/hacktohell) doesn't take complete security suites (e.g. for Kaspersky, it only took Kaspersky Anti Virus and not Kaspersky Internet Security). IMO, Windows Defender must be compared to KIS and not KAV.