# Antivirus in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, anti-virus

I have been using Windows 8 for a while, and I have just remembered that I did not install any antivirus software. To my surprise, I don't think Windows 8 has ever shown any of the usual nag popups that appeared in Windows 7, Vista, or XP if you didn't keep an up-to-date antivirus.

Is there a default antivirus in Windows 8 already installed? Or is the nag popup just disabled?

Comment: [Does Windows 8 require any sort of Virus protection?](http://superuser.com/questions/494074/does-windows-8-require-any-sort-of-virus-protection)

Comment: @Karan: is there an antivirus is a different question than do I need an antivirus.

Comment: Which is why I simply provided the link as a cross-ref, and didn't vote to close.

Comment: @Karan: others did though, probably due to misinterpreting your comment :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Microsoft Security Essentials is now built in to Windows 8, it has been integrated in to [Windows Defender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Defender#Windows_8). See [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/494274/25625) on instructions on how to access the features