# Do I need another anti-virus other than Defender?

Tags: windows-8, anti-virus, windows-defender

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Windows 8 require any sort of Virus protection?](https://superuser.com/questions/494074/does-windows-8-require-any-sort-of-virus-protection)

Jut got new laptop with win8 - the question is if I need some extra AV than windows 8 defender? On my PC with win7 I use only Security Essentials and no other AV and I don't have any problems. I read that win8 defender is the same thing as MSE...

Comment: @amiregelz you can also flag the post with dupe link for mod attention. :-)

Comment: @avirk I did, I just commented so other people will flag the post as well :)

Comment: @amiregelz Yup. And we can VTC for it.  ;-)

Comment: @amiregelz: "I did, I just commented so other people will flag the post as well" - Looks like you forgot to mark as dupe after all. Anyway, don't worry, we did it on your behalf. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft built Windows Defender/MSE into Windows 8 is a full fledged Anti-Virus. You do not need another AV.

Comment: It probably isn't the absolute best antivirus program out there. But Microsoft Security Essentials and Windows Defender together place reasonably well in reviews and are free. If you need wholistic and annoying levels of security, go ahead and pay for it. But odds are you'll be fine with the default and included tools.

Comment: @music2myear - If MSE was good enough for the user then Windows Defender which is the exact same engine then it should be good enough.

Comment: I hadn't looked at the security system built into 8 and so was still assuming they were two different things. I'm interested in why they went with the name of the product superseded by MSE in 8.